# How to disable auto recover?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2007

I've tried disabling "Save AutoRecover information" option, but to no avail. The window "Excel has recovered the following files" still pops up at the start.
Any other ideas?

UPD Auto-recover window is shown each start after I terminate Excel during my debug session. 
All file entries Excel shows in the auto-recover window are dated by year 1601. I checked Excel auto-recover folder, and there is no any real file there.

Comment: What are you really trying to do then...?

Comment: @soandos, I want auto-recover stop working.

Comment: are you recovering new files, or just getting notices about the old ones?

Comment: @soandos, I don't want any files recovered, that's why I disabled auto-recover option. But it still tries to perform auto-recover, this is a problem I'm trying to solve.

Answer (score 1):

try this:

1. kill all your sessions of excel (make sure by eliminating any excel.exe processes in task manager)
2. start a new session of excel
3. load your workbook
4. make your setting
5. save your workbook
6. close excel
7. start a new excel session
8. open your workbook
9. verify the setting has persisted.