# Excel auto-recover is eating up all 16GB of RAM and never loading the 32MB file its choking on

Tags: windows-7, microsoft-excel, memory, crash

I've read every auto-recover question I can find, and while some would be useful IF the file would ever appear, this seems different.

I was working with a very large data set. I copied and pasted that data set into a table that does fairly extensive calculations on that raw data in its last few columns (*if this ever loads, I need to check the order of the columns... possible issue is that the operations are out of order, left to right, creating loops of processing. Never noticeable with smaller data sets (a few thousand rows) but maybe a game changer at tens of thousands of rows...*)

The table took about 5 hours to finish processing. I tried to save it, but in that time my computer had lost its network drives (another annoying issue) so I saved it to a network location (same as the network drive, just using the IP address rather than the name of the server. Seemed to save fine.)

I rebooted to clear RAM and everything, and tried to open the saved document. Excel showed the file as corrupted and took another 5 or so hours to finish error checking it. It had removed the table formatting, and a bunch of the formulas were lost... all totally fine, easily recoverable. I saved the file LOCALLY to avoid any network issues.

I try to open the file and gave up after it took HOURS and never opened. However, more than one Excel process starts up, and the second one balloons up to the full 16GB of RAM on the computer (Windows 7, Office 2016, 3.2 MHz, quad core, everything fully updated).

I even tried just opening a new empty document. It's opened just fine, but another Excel process shows up in Process Explorer and steadily grows, until it eats up 100% of available memory, 0-1% CPU. The empty workbook is nearly unusable, with a 6-10 second delay between keyboard/mouse input and a reaction.

I've seen the instructions [to turn off auto-save/recover](https://superuser.com/questions/296813/how-to-disable-auto-recover) from WITHIN a document, but if the document never loads, that seems impossible to achieve.

I know there are [switches](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/command-line-switches-for-microsoft-office-products-079164cd-4ef5-4178-b235-441737deb3a6#ID0EAABAAA=Excel) that can be added to the basic excel.exe command, but none of the ones I could find pertained to disabling auto-recover. I can't even find the tmp file auto-recover is theoretically trying to auto-recover. I would just delete that and minimize my losses.

What worries me is that it's happening even just trying to start a new workbook, so the old workaround of "just copy the data into a new workbook" is out the window because I can't get it to finish loading so I can create a new workbook. I can't even start the project from scratch (sob!), because Excel drags itself to a halt with this phantom auto-recover process.

**So, long question short: How to bypass auto-recovery (and any other "helpful" features) at launch for Excel?**

Comment: May have found the temp files. Users/username/AppData/Roaming/Microsoft/Excel. I had just followed all the basic online advice about checking AppData/LOCAL/M$/Excel... but there were definitely files in the Roaming folder...

Comment: Removing temp files didn't accomplish anything. Did try the /s flag to enter safe-mode. Got told there are documents in need of recovering but that it'll happen next time. Tried to open the recovered and locally saved version of the file... 10 minutes ago... still opening. RAM is maxed out. Seems... unlikely.

Comment: You need more ram, when it runs out of ram it uses the hard drive as memory, which is slow as hell.

Comment: 16GB for a 34MB document. I'm guessing the RAM isn't actually the problem here.

Comment: "I was working with a very large data set" I assumed it was a typo, as 34mb is not a "very large" data set.

Comment: Fair enough. Usually use the table handles a few thousand rows (a year or two worth of enrollment data), and in this case I was taking information from our previous enrollment system and plugging 10 years of data into it. So, large, comparatively, but still in the 10s of thousands of rows range, probably not "enterprise large" though. :) I would have assumed the file was bigger after all that... but it is what it is...

Answer (score 0):

Deleting out all the temp files in both 
 `Users/username/AppData/**Roaming**/Microsoft/Excel` 
 and
 `Users/username/AppData/**Local**/Microsoft/Excel` 
seems to have taken care of Excel crashing trying to auto-recover this corrupted file every time I tried to start Excel, except with the /s flag, as noted in the comments.

In other news, huzzah for shadow copies on the server. I was able to find a version where I only lose 2 days worth of work, and not 5. :D I'll take it!

Answer (score 0):

Additional answer/observation: I started adding rows of data to the table, in increasing increments (literally 2 rows, then 20, then 200, then 1,000). Everything seemed to be going really smoothly...I started adding a few thousand rows at a time, which would take a few seconds to process, but nothing concerning. I realized I still had Process Explorer open, and saw the memory usage bumping up with each addition of rows to the table. I deleted a few thousand, and the memory came right back down.

So, Excel Tables (compared to a regular spreadsheet) seem to take up much more RAM, and in a fairly linear fashion. I started putting a thousand or so rows in the table, getting all the parsing/revisions/edits I need, then copying as values to another a sheet, and deleting out of the table.

Another possible point: At least two of the formulas compare values down a column, which may have duplicates, and prints it just ONCE in the next column. So, its always scanning all values in the column... which seems like it might create an insane amount of overhead, compared to a formula that just concatenates values or modifies data based on how its formatted (123abc456 vs abc456 vs 123abc456.78 etc). Those just work across the row, not by scanning the entire column.